# AMP for mobile and Bootstap for Desktop

Tags: amp, css-framework

I was just curious if I can develop a website that will be AMP for mobile and Bootstrap or whatever framework for Desktop.

And if I can do this without a redirect so Google search from mobiles will give me a priority due to Amp page.
Is it possible or the only way it to build two pages with different URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do so. You just have to include a link ref=cannonical tag for the same. You can do a simple search and checkout https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/basic_markup